# How to use Lookup to edit data in database?

Tags: delphi

I have another problem, I have a database with UserID's with data.
I want an option to edit that data en write it in the right line.

We can "edit" data, but it makes a whole new line in the database, 
How can i overwrite existing data in the table?

I have to use lookup but how?

This is the code:

```
    procedure TfmKlant.BTOpslaanClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    dm.atInlog.Open;
  gevonden := false;
    while (not gevonden) and (not dm.atInlog.eof) do
    begin
        if dm.atInlog['email'] = fminloggen.inlognaam
      then
      begin
         // plaats gegevens in de textboxen
        gevonden := true;
        dm.atInlog.Append;
        dm.atInlog['naam']        := leNaam.text;
        dm.atInlog['adres']       := leAdres.text;
        dm.atInlog['postcode']    := lePostcode.text;
        dm.atInlog['telefoon']    := leTelefoonnummer.text;
        dm.atInlog['email']       := leEmail.text;
        dm.atInlog['password']    := lePassword.text;
        dm.atInlog.Post;
      end
        else
    dm.atInlog.Next;
    end;
        leemail.Clear;
        lenaam.Clear;
        leadres.clear;
        lepostcode.clear;
        letelefoonnummer.clear;
        lepassword.clear;
end;
```

Comment: that is a table. It is created and connected in a datamodule

Comment: There's no "table" component in my palette, but if your "table" derives from TDataSet, you don't need to manually iterate over all records to reach the record you want.  Use the Locate method, or, if the DataSet supports indexes, use the fastest FindKey method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dm.atInlog.Edit;` instead of `dm.atInlog.Append;` in your code

Comment: We are very stupid :') that did the trick, you have no idea how long we have been sitting on that problem